# I want to import multiple files and make it into object string

Tags: c#

So I want to make the program to read multiple txt files and turn it into some object. I'm just started to learn C# and I don't know if I'm doing into right direction or not.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should probably look at taking all the code that's been repeated and combine it into 1 method, which simply takes a file name and then call that (3 times in your example).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole content of the file in 1x string, you could use:

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("filePath");
```

The StreamReader is a good way to give you more control over the reading of the file.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-from-a-text-file
and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0

However your example doesn't create an object. It open each file and return true. Could you give more details as of what you want at the end ?

**UPDATE:**

For the same output your code could be "simplified " or refactored to:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Toto;

public class CPHInline {
    public bool Execute() {
        try {
            var message = $"{GetContent("yourPath1")}{GetContent("yourPath2")}{GetContent("yourPath1")}";
            CPH.SendMessage(File.ReadAllText(message));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string GetContent(string filePath) {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        return null;
    }
}
```

or if async was possible you could do:
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

```
public class CPHInline {
    public async Task Execute()
    {
        var readers = new List<Task<string>> {
            GetContentAsync("filePath1"),
            GetContentAsync("filePath2"),
            GetContentAsync("filePath2")
        };
        var message = string.Empty;
        while (readers.Any()) {
            var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(readers);
            readers.Remove(finishedTask);

            //Concatenate the result
            var content = await finishedTask;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content) == false)
                message += content;
        }

        CPH.SendMessage(message);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetContentAsync(string filePath)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            return await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use it in CPH.SendMessage, so I can call the text value, and the bot will send message.

CPH.SendMessage(Text1+Text2+Text3)